# Filtering a list of key value pair, if key do not exist

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Here we have a List of Param objects which have basically two properties-
1. Name
2. Value

I am trying to get value of a param having a specific name using stream-

```
return paramList.stream().filter(param -> 
param.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("param_name"))
                .findAny()
                .map(param -> param.getValue()).get();
```

But this method gives me NullPointerException if there is no such Param object in list having name "param_name". How can I avoide it and get a null value instead.

Comment: Read the javadoc of Optional. It's all explained there. It's always a good idea to read the javadoc of the classes that you're using.

Comment: [Java 8 Optional Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) ... look at `get` and `orElse`. Could it also be, that your `getName` may have `null`s?

Comment: Param's getName() is never null, its just that it  might possible, none of element in the list have name property = "param_name", which I am searching for

Comment: `Optional.get()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException` if the optional is empty. So if you get a `NullPointerException`, there must be a different reason. Look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that one of the `getName()`-calls throws a `NullPointerException`, as `get()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` if it is empty and there are no other possible `null`s except the `paramList` itself.

One possible solution to get a default value, if you can't find a `param` with `"param_name"` is:

```
paramList.stream()
         .filter(Objects::nonNull) // filters out null params
         .filter(param -> Objects.nonNull(param.getName())) // filters out params with name null
         .filter(param -> param.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("param_name"))
         .findAny()
         .map(param -> param.getValue()) // or .map(ParamClass::getValue)
         .orElse(null); // your default
```

You may also want to have a look at the [`Optional` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

If your `getName`-method does more than we are actually expecting here, you may need to surround it with a `try/catch`-statement.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter those optionals that are not present for example. Something like this

```
.map(param -> param.getValue())
.filter(Optional::isPresent)
.map(Optional::get)
.findAny()
.orElse("Not Found");
```